# Grails 3.0 / IntelliJ 14.1.4 creating controllers, services, domain classes not working

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, gradle

When I try to create a Grails domain class, controller (anything, really) using IntelliJ 14.1.4 results in failures from the Gradle commands that IntelliJ is calling, for instance:

```
9:29:45 AM: Executing external task 'grails-create-domain-class -PgrailsArgs="Koos --non-interactive -plain-output"'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'grails-create-domain-class' not found in root project 'Koos'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.326 secs
Task 'grails-create-domain-class' not found in root project 'Koos'.
9:29:47 AM: External task execution finished 'grails-create-domain-class -PgrailsArgs="Koos --non-interactive -plain-output"'.
```

The Gradle project is pulled in, the Grails view is active on this project.
**Is this an IntelliJ bug? Am I doing something wrong? If I call this directly on the CLI it also fails.**

---

These are the steps to reproduce the error:
Install Grails 3.0 using gvm tool:

```
gvm install grails
```

Check version:

```
grails --version
```

Result:

```
Grails Version: 3.0.4
Groovy Version: 2.4.4
JVM Version: 1.8.0_45
```

Create an app:

```
grails create-app Koos
```

After pulling the needed jars from the intertubes, it says Application created
Create the Idea projects:

```
gradle idea
```

Then open the project with IntelliJ. After configuring the gradle import, right-clicking on domains and selecting "Create Domain Class" results in the error.

Comment: tried grails create-domain-class myDomain ? from the cli you can verify its version using CLI so why not create it that way if you are stuck. It does sound like some issue with intellij

Comment: 'grails-create-domain-class' see it ? 'grails create-domain-class' there is a dash connecting grails-create

Comment: grails create-domain-class myDomain does work. Either the Idea integration is borked for 3.0 or I'm doing something wrong (which, after using 2.4 and earlier extensively I'm pretty sure there's no PEBKAC here).

Comment: First, you need to upgrade Intellij to 15. You have to try CLI to create domain class. refer https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Command%20Line/create-domain-class.html :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually IntelliJ 14.1.4 still not support the command line command of Grails 3.0.x I think build system gradle is the fact. Intellij idea can not apply this build system for Grails yet.